# Como converter 10:00:00 em 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Estou fazendo um programa que calcula hora e multiplica por um valor.

Porém, usando a biblioteca `datetime`, eu obtenho o tempo no formato `"10:00:00"`, e se eu multiplicar por `14.00` ele me retorna um erro, pois não existe o horário 140.

Aí que está o problema, o Python interpreta que estou multiplicando o horário `"10:00:00"` por 14, sendo que quero multiplicar apenas o 10 por 14. Dito isso, como eu converto `"10:00:00"` em `10` ou `"15:40:00"` em `15.40`? para obter o horário estou usando a função `strptime()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que entender dois conceitos diferentes: datas/horas e durações. Considere as frases abaixo:

- o evento será às 10 horas
- o evento durou 10 horas

No primeiro caso, "10 horas" é um horário: um momento específico do dia.

No segundo caso, "10 horas" é uma duração: uma quantidade de tempo (não diz que hora começou ou terminou, diz somente quanto tempo durou).

O que pode confundir é que ambos usam as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos, segundos), e podem até mesmo ser mostrados do mesmo jeito (um relógio mostra "10:00" quando é 10h, um cronômetro mostra "10:00" para indicar que se passaram 10 horas). Mas eles são conceitos diferentes.

Dito isso, no módulo `datetime` temos classes que representam datas/horas (como `datetime`, `date` e `time`) e [uma que representa durações (`timedelta`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). E você disse que usou `strptime`, que no caso serve para trabalhar com datas e horas, mas não com durações. Por isso não vai funcionar.

---

No seu caso, acredito que "10:00:00" represente uma duração de 10 horas, pois só assim faz sentido multiplicá-la por um número. Se fosse um horário, não faria sentido, pois qual deveria ser o resultado de "10 da manhã vezes 14"? Mas se for uma duração de 10 horas, aí faz sentido, pois ao multiplicar por 14, teríamos uma duração de 140 horas.

Infelizmente não há uma forma direta de fazer o *parsing* de um `timedelta` (não existe equivalente a `strptime`), então o jeito é fazer manualmente:

```
from datetime import timedelta

s = "10:00:00"
horas, minutos, segundos = map(int, s.split(':'))
duracao = timedelta(hours=horas, minutes=minutos, seconds=segundos)

# multiplicando por 14
nova_duracao = duracao * 14
# obter o total de horas
print(nova_duracao.total_seconds() / 3600) # 140.0
```

Para obter o total de horas, basta usar o valor de `total_seconds` e dividir por 3600.

Um detalhe: se a entrada for `15:40:00`, isso **não** é equivalente a `15.4`, pois 40 minutos equivalem a 0,66666... horas, então uma duração de 15 horas e 40 minutos equivale a 15,66666... horas (que multiplicado por 14, dará 219.33333... horas).